# Is there new update for POI sorting function?

Tags: apache-poi

Is there a new feature released?  I found all questions in this case,and don't get any answer about it.

I hope I can order a column to sort when I export to excel by POI. It 's dynamic. I get the data and display UI, when user click one of columns to sort data. I can got which column to sort by UI, but I don't know how to write sort in POI. I can't found any attribute I can use. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goR9B.jpg)
  My UI is a 4fd file

Comment: What is "POI sorting function"? `Apache poi` is software for handling `Microsoft Office` file formats and many of the Office applications provides sorting but of course not all the same way. So please be more specific about what you want.

Comment: I hope I can order a column to sort when I export to excel by POI. It 's dynamic.
I get the data and display UI, when user click one of columns to sort data. I can got which column to sort by UI, but I don't know how to write sort in POI. I can't found any attribute I can use.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe your problem there and not here in a comment. But even your comment is not clear enough. If you have a UI displaying the data, then this UI should have methods to sort data. POI is only for creating the Excel file and should get the sorted data already. So what kind of UI you have? And what is stopping you implementing a sort method in this UI?